# Share data between sibling components if data is not already persisted to Vuex?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

If I have two sibling components that share the same data and that data is **not** already persisted to `Vuex` (e.g. a direct page load to `api/v1/calendars/:id`, would making a call to that resource within both components be necessary? I have read the following:

> Vue components should be as self-contained and isolated as much as
>   possible

If that is true, then requesting the data from `Vuex` from within both components is correct, but the application would be making two network calls when only one is required if that data is not already available in `Vuex`.

Ideally I would like to make a single network call for the required resource, then multiple components on that page all share the data within `Vuex`.

I would be duplicating this code in both components, specifically the `created()` method.

```
<script>
import store from '@state/store'
import { calendarComputed } from '@state/helpers'

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      calendar: null,
    }
  },
  computed: {
    ...calendarComputed,
  },
  created() {
    // Are calendars already persisted?
    if (!this.calendars.length) {
      store.dispatch('calendar/getCalendars').then((res) => {
        this.calendar = res.find((calendar) => { if (calendar.id == this.$route.params.id) return calendar })
      })
    } else {
      this.calendar = this.calendars.find((calendar) => { if (calendar.id == this.$route.params.id) return calendar })
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: Vuex is there to handle these kinds of issues. _"but the application would be making two network calls when only one is required"_ that's an issue with the vuex setup. Maybe post that code instead/as-well

Comment: How are the components related? You will need to pick one component, or router event that will make the request. I recently wrote a blog post on vuex that uses two components sharing data if you would like to see an example https://medium.com/js-dojo/maintaining-a-single-source-of-truth-while-handling-form-data-with-vuex-426e86d16642

Comment: If the components are siblings, would it not make sense to make the request from their parent and pass the data in as props?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would be to make your components not (explicitly) care about whether the calendars have been fetched.

Simply tell the store to fetch, but the action decides if it actually needs to do so.

Vuex is supposed to be one-way data flow, so status info does not come back from the action to the component, instead the component always just waits for the data to arrive.

To make things reactive, use a combination of `computed` and `getter`.

**component**

```js
created() {
  /* tell the store 'this is what I need' */
  store.dispatch('calendar/getCalendars');
},
...
computed: {
  calendar() {
    /* reactive - initially null, then gets a value when the store is updated */
    return this.$store.getters['calendar/calendarById'](this.$route.params.id)
  },
},
```

**store**

```js
getters: {
  calendarById: (state) => {
    /* return a function so that param can be passed from component */
    return (id) => state.calendars ? state.calendars.find(c => c.id === id) : null;
  },
}

actions: {
  getCalendars (store) {
    /* only perform the fetch if the store does not already contain the data */
    if (!store.state.calendars) {
      fetch(calendarsUrl).then(res => store.commit('setCalendars', res); // e.g
    }
  },
}
```